# RabbitMQ: how a Queue can be auto-deleted?

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I have N customers, each of them has its own Queue using fanout exchange:
Que-1
Que-2
...
Que-N

Publishers published messages to to fanout exchange, i.e. Publisher->pub msg->(to all Que-1 - Que-N)

Each customer reads its own queue
customer i - reads -Que-i

The question is:

How can I solve this problem: if no customer reads this Que-* in K minutes then this Que should be deleted with messages.
I.e. publishers can publish messages, but if no customer reads it then it should be dropped.

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#properties      Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: But what parameter can I use? i.e. if no customer reads this que in K minutes it should be dropped.

Comment: You can create a service to drop the old q messages. After that the auto-delete parameter in the q should do the job.

Comment: Ok, thanx @StPaulis, write your answer and I will mark it.

Comment: No worry, I don't care about points so much :) Wish I helped

Answer (score 1):

The parameter x-expires does what I need:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-expires", 1800000);
channel.queueDeclare("myqueue", false, false, false, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

TTL can also be set on queues, not just queue contents. Queues will expire after a period of time only when they are not used (e.g. do not have consumers). This feature can be used together with the [auto-delete queue property](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html).

Expiry time can be set for a given queue by setting the `x-expires` argument to `queue.declare`, or by setting the `expires` policy. This controls for how long a queue can be unused before it is automatically deleted. Unused means the queue has no consumers, the queue has not been recently redeclared (redeclaring renews the lease), and `basic.get` has not been invoked for a duration of at least the expiration period.

The value of the `x-expires` argument or `expires` policy describes the expiration period in milliseconds. It must be a positive integer (unlike message TTL it cannot be 0). Thus a value of 1000 means a queue which is unused for 1 second will be deleted.

**Define Queue TTL for Queues Using a Policy**

The following policy makes all queues expire after 30 minutes since last use:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy expiry ".*" '{"expires":1800000}' --apply-to queues
```

**Define Queue TTL for Queues Using x-arguments During Declaration**

This example in Java creates a queue which expires after it has been unused for 30 minutes.

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-expires", 1800000);
channel.queueDeclare("myqueue", false, false, false, args);
```

See the link below for more details:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html